# сравнение элементов двух одномерных массивов

Tags: php

есть 2 массива:
массив с группами для полей
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Легковые авто
            [description] => Поля с характеристиками для легковых авто
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [title] => Недвижимость
        [description] => Группа для полей к объявлениям о недвижимости
    )

 )
```

и массив для связи полей которые относятся к этим группам:
     Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32
            [id_field] => 12
            [id_fieldsgroup] => 2
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 33
        [id_field] => 12
        [id_fieldsgroup] => 3
    )

 )
```

как можно сравнить эти два массива чтоб при совпадении элементов были выделены все  для которых $fgl['id'] == $fgff['id_fieldsgroup']
 я пробовал сделать так, но это не верно:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                <select name="id_group[]" multiple="true" id="id_group" class="form-control col-xs-12">
                    <?php if(!empty($FieldsGroupList)):?>
                        <?php foreach($FieldsGroupList as $fgl): ?>
                            <?php foreach ($getFieldsGroupForField as $fgff): ?>
                            <?php if ($fgl['id'] == $fgff['id_fieldsgroup']): ?>
                            <option value="<?=$fgl['id']?>" selected><?=$fgl['title']?> - <?=$fgl['description']?></option>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <option value="0">Нужно создать группы!</option>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

при таком коде выделяются только  для которых совпало условие, остальные  вообще не выводятся, как исправить??

Comment: Опишите грамотно, что вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: Я хочу построить список селект с множественным выбором чтоб были выбраны те  <option> для которых $fgl['id'] == $fgff['id_fieldsgroup']

Comment: Ну так вы сделайте чтобы по условию не тэг option создавался, а только класс selected ставился. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы остальные варианты выводились, а нужные были только выделены надо условие повесить на отображение класса `selected`, а не на отрисовку тэга.

Вместо:

```
<?php if ($fgl['id'] == $fgff['id_fieldsgroup']): ?>
    <option value="<?=$fgl['id']?>" selected><?=$fgl['title']?> - <?=$fgl['description']?></option>
<?php endif ?>
```

Нужно:

```
<option value="<?=$fgl['id']?>" <?= ($fgl['id'] == $fgff['id_fieldsgroup']) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?=$fgl['title']?> - <?=$fgl['description']?></option>
```

Или так:

```
<?php if ($fgl['id'] == $fgff['id_fieldsgroup']): ?>
    $selected = 'selected';
<?php endif ?>
<option value="<?=$fgl['id']?>" <?= $selected ?>><?=$fgl['title']?> - <?=$fgl['description']?></option>
```

Comment: А как тоже самое сделать на javascript??

Comment: что именно "тоже самое"? если прописываение атрибута selected, то непонятно зачем. Если хотите переписать все на js, то берете и начинаете переписывать. Пробуйте, а не получится делайте новый вопрос и прикладывайте свой код. За вас никто писать просто так ничего не будет.